# Disambiguate YAGO classes with wordnet using python

Tags: python, wordnet

Classes in the YAGO knowledge graph are in the form wordnet_XXX_YYY where XXX is the name of the class and YYY is the synset id from wordnet. So for example the URI for the class airport is http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/wordnet_airport_102692232 .

Therefore, because of the different meanings of a word, YAGO may have many classes with the same XXX and different YYY depending on the meaning.

How can I find the definition of a word given the YYY? On their website https://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/databases-and-information-systems/research/yago-naga/yago/faq/ it says that YYY are synset ids, but the tool returns airport.n.01 as synset id.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You have to run the SPARQL query in your machine by using the YAGO guideline for extracting information from YAGO ontology. 
For your questions, I hope the following python code will give you the required results.

````html
```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON
sparql.setQuery("""
    select  *
where {
        <http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/wordnet_XXX_YYY> <http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/hasGloss> ?GlossValues.
      } 
    """)
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
results = sparql.query().convert()
#print(results)

for result in results["results"]["bindings"]:
    print(result)
```
````